# Can not install jdownloader in 18.04

Tags: package-management, jdownloader

I tried to install jdownloader, I added the ppa then got error `Unable to locate package jdownloader-installer`
 when I tried to install it.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jdownloader-installer
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a problem to be addressed by the ppa owner?

Comment: The latest Ubuntu version supported by the PPA is 17.10, as you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/ubuntu/jdownloader)

Comment: @waltinator In this case, I can't do anything until the owner fix it?